# Can a low density subset sum problem be intractable?

Tags: complexity

Hardness of a subset sum problem depends on it's density.

Is it possible for a subset sum problem to be intractable even if it's density is less than 0.9408?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. ​ ​ ​ By reduction from [1-in-3-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Exactly-1_3-satisfiability), subset sum remains

NP-hard when the subset's size is part of the input, so we can

[add an arbitrarily large number to each element

and ​ (that_number)*(subset_size) ​ to the target]

to get that for all positive integers c, [subset sum with density less than 1/(1+(n^c))] is NP-hard.

Here's a much better question: ​ "Is it possible for a subset sum problem to be"

strongly hard-on-average "even if it's density is less than 0.9408?"

(I do not know the answer to the better question.)